# Processing Time with SVM

Tags: python, svm

I am new to the world of SVM, and am trying to teach myself through tutorials.  I recently tried to create a sample svm test, however, the `run-time` appears to be endless. What is a typical processing time given that my `dataframe` has 7976 rows?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd
import os

directory_name = 'D:\Timothy\Practice SVM\Data'
name_of_file = 'Sample_SVM.csv'

df_start = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory_name, name_of_file))
df_cleaned = df_start.dropna()

X = df_cleaned.ix[1:8000, 'Sun'].as_matrix()
X = X.reshape((7976,1))  #unsure if this step is needed
X_test = df_cleaned.ix[8000:9913, 'Sun'].as_matrix()

y = df_cleaned.ix[1:8000, 'Meter_Total'].as_matrix()
y_test = df_cleaned.ix[8000:9913, 'Meter_Total'].as_matrix()

model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, gamma=1)

model.fit(X,y)
model.score(X, y)

predicted = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Is your data normalized?

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: When you use the term 'run-time' it can be either 'training time' or 'test time' ( in the given program )but since you said that the dataframe has 7976 rows, I am going to consider it as training time.

Considering Linear SVMs, at training time one must estimate vector w and bias b by solving a quadratic problem, thereby finding the support vectors.
In general, testing whether one has arrived at an optimal solution requires order of n² dot products and solving the quadratic problem involves inversion of 'kernel' matrix, this is of the order of n³. ( here, n is number of samples in the training set ). However, one hardly ever needs to estimate the optimal solution; and the training time for a linear SVM to reach a certain level of generalisation error actually decreases as training set size increases. Generally, this depends a lot on what techniques one is using, but expect to have training times of the order of n² for all but state-of-the-art linear SVMs or approximate solvers.

Precisely, for scikit-learn packages, (n_sample * n_features) for linear SVMs such as liblinear also noting that strong regularization (low C) makes it faster to converge too.